# SQL to summarise solar power generated by quarter

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a single MySQL table with 10 years of solar panel generation data (every 10 minutes, where generation is > zero).

I have no idea how to construct a query that will give me four values per year row, each value representing the summed total for each quarter in that year.

My source table (DTP) schema looks like this:

```
#,  Field,      Type,           Null,   Key,    Default,    Extra
1,  'PWR',      'decimal(5,3)', 'NO',   '',     NULL,       ''
2,  'idDTP',    'int(11)',      'NO',   'PRI',  NULL,       'auto_increment'
3,  'DT',       'datetime',     'NO',   '',     NULL,       ''
```

One example I though might point me in the right direction looks like this (bear in mind this is partly modified from the source):

```
SELECT Year,SUM(Quarter1) AS Quarter1,SUM(Quarter2) AS Quarter2,SUM(Quarter3) AS Quarter3,SUM(Quarter4) AS Quarter4
FROM
(
    SELECT YEAR(DT) AS 'Year' ,
    Quarter1 = CASE(DATEPART(q, DTP.DT))
    WHEN 1 THEN SUM(DTP.DT)
    ELSE 0
    END,
    Quarter2 = CASE(DATEPART(q, DTP.DT))
    WHEN 2 THEN SUM(DTP.DT)
    ELSE 0
    END,
    Quarter3 = CASE(DATEPART(q, DTP.DT))
    WHEN 3 THEN SUM(DTP.DT)
    ELSE 0
    END,
    Quarter4 = CASE(DATEPART(q, DTP.DT))
    WHEN 4 THEN SUM(DTP.DT)
    ELSE 0
    END
 FROM DTP LEFT JOIN PWR ON DTP.DT = Customers.CustomerID
 LEFT JOIN [Order Details] ON [Order Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID
 GROUP BY CompanyName, YEAR(OrderDate), DATEPART(q, OrderDate)
 )C
 GROUP BY CompanyName,Year
```

I started trying to convert it to my scenario but without understanding it, I've landed myself in a half finished (assuming this is even on the right lines) mess and I'm not sure how to fix it. Any well explained hints or links would be welcome - flames, less so. ;oP

If I've got the wrong forum, please politely point out the right one - couldn't see a better alternative in the Stack-Echange list.

Thanks
Small sample from first year of source data (Feb-Mar)

```
'160851', '2012-02-29 08:00:00', '0.030'
'160852', '2012-02-29 08:10:00', '0.066'
'160853', '2012-02-29 08:20:00', '0.072'
'160854', '2012-02-29 08:30:00', '0.060'
'160855', '2012-02-29 08:40:00', '0.090'
'160856', '2012-02-29 08:50:00', '0.102'
'160857', '2012-02-29 09:00:00', '0.084'
'160858', '2012-02-29 09:10:00', '0.132'
'160859', '2012-02-29 09:20:00', '0.144'
'160860', '2012-02-29 09:30:00', '0.138'
'160861', '2012-02-29 09:40:00', '0.150'
'160862', '2012-02-29 09:50:00', '0.174'
'160863', '2012-02-29 10:00:00', '0.174'
'160864', '2012-02-29 10:10:00', '0.162'
```

I can't enter a years worth of data, as it unsurprisingly exceeds the allowed count but it proceeds in a similar vein.

There's no meaningful output because I got out of my depth well before I'd approached anything like viable code.

Comment: Can you share input samples and corresponding output samples?

Comment: your query show multiple tables, and tzhe query seems to be sound, should you not sum up the pwr up the pwr coplumn

Answer (score 1):

Define a new year-quarter column, named `yq`.
Fill it with values like `"2021-q4"` and `"2022-q1"`.

Now your problem is simple.
Just compute `SUM( ... )`
with `GROUP BY yq`.

Comment: Thanks J_H. I'll give that a go tomorrow (too late to try now) :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some tables, but i kept them in the subquery.

the subwquery, would show the numbers for all quaters , for every company and year.

The outer query, would, sum them up into years without companies..

As you need more columns you can add them from comapanies orders or order details and add them in the inner `SELECT` and then add them also in the outer, to group them for them examle by orders or such

```
SELECT Year,SUM(Quarter1) AS Quarter1,SUM(Quarter2) AS Quarter2,SUM(Quarter3) AS Quarter3,SUM(Quarter4) AS Quarter4
FROM
(
    SELECT  CompanyName,YEAR(DT) AS 'Year' ,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(q, DTP.DT)  =  1 THEN DTP.PWR ELSe 0 END)  Quarter1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(q, DTP.DT)  =  2 THEN DTP.PWR ELSe 0 END) Quarter2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(q, DTP.DT)  =  3 THEN DTP.PWR ELSe 0 END)  Quarter3,
            SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(q, DTP.DT)  =  4 THEN DTP.PWR ELSe 0 END) Quarter4
 FROM DTP LEFT JOIN PWR ON DTP.DT = Customers.CustomerID
 LEFT JOIN [Order Details] ON [Order Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID
 GROUP BY CompanyName, YEAR(OrderDate)
 ) C
 GROUP BY Year
```

Without the customer and orders

```
SELECT  CompanyName,YEAR(DT) AS 'Year' ,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(q, DTP.DT)  =  1 THEN DTP.PWR ELSe 0 END)  Quarter1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(q, DTP.DT)  =  2 THEN DTP.PWR ELSe 0 END) Quarter2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(q, DTP.DT)  =  3 THEN DTP.PWR ELSe 0 END)  Quarter3,
            SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(q, DTP.DT)  =  4 THEN DTP.PWR ELSe 0 END) Quarter4
 FROM DTP 
 GROUP BY  YEAR(DT)
```

Comment: I'm sure you're right but you've misunderstood. Anything to do with 'orders' & 'customers' was a remnant of the original example and DT (datetime) and PWR (kW) are what I'm trying to sum per quarter

Comment: the qiery makes exact what you wanted. try it, if you don't need the custere or order table, then remove it form the qiery and group only by the year,

Comment: Thanks for trying NBK, but can I just point out the only table involved is the one at the top of my original post (and a few sample lines of data a bit further down. My confusion is from using an example and not knowing how to reconcile the example's working mechanism with my different and simpler data structure. If I took it out by making it work, I wouldn't be posting and if I removed the references to the example structure there would be random edits that make even less sense.

Comment: you make no sense, you have a simpe table with three columns, and you want ti sum up the PWR column and DT defines whch quarter and year.  so when you run my second query, it should yield some results. From here you can explain your problem, but now you don't make any sense